# Separate NULL from non existence

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

I having a code which makes select:

```
val requestId = 123
DB.withConnection { implicit con =>
  SQL("SELECT my_field FROM my_table WHERE some_id = {request_id}").onParams(requestId)()
   .collect {
      case Row(myField: Option[String]) =>
        myField match {
          case Some(x) =>
            // ???   

          case None => //there is no such a record?
         }
      }
  }
```

`my_field` can be `NULL`. Thus there are 3 options:

1. the record `WHERE some_id = request_id` doesn't exist
2. the record `WHERE some_id = request_id` exists and has a value
3. the record `WHERE some_id = request_id` exists and is `NULL`

How do I separate 1 and 3?

Comment: Does collect even iterate over a row when it doesn't exist?

Comment: No, there will be no rows, so collect will return an empty list/seq or whatever it's returning.

Comment: @SteveSowerby, in what case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only limited experience with Anorm since I have jumped on the Slick bandwagon, but I think you distinguish among your cases this way (in order):

1. You get an empty collection back.
2. You get a `Some` back.
3. You get a `None` back.

So I would guess you match like this:

```
        myField match {
          case Seq() => //the record doesn't exist
          case Some(x) => //unpack x because you found something    
          case None => //the record exists but some_id = NULL
         }
```

Check the Anorm documentation to see what kind of collection you get back. `List` does implement the `Seq` trait though.

Comment: what should I return in `myField match `?

Comment: should it be `case Row(myField: Option[String]) => myField`?

Comment: See my edit. Hopefully it gets you really close if not all the way. Again, I am not an Anorm dude.

Comment: please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768272/pattern-matching-on-stream-option-and-creating-a-tuple this is where I'm stuck.