# Pattern matching on Stream, Option and creating a Tuple

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, anorm

I have a table `table1`:

```
id: Int
externalId: Int
value: String
```

For a given `externalId` `value` can be `NULL` or it might not exist at all. I want to return a tuple depending on this condition:

1. If it doesn't exist then return `("notExists", Nil)`
2. If it exists but `NULL` then return `("existsButNull", Nil)`
3. If it exists and not `NULL` then return `("existsWithValue", ???)`

where `???` should be a list of `value` for all records with the given `externalId`. I tried to do this:

```
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  SQL("SELECT value from table1 WHERE externalId = 333")
    .map { case Row(value: Option[String]) => value }
} match {
  case Some(x) #:: xs =>
    //????????????
    ("existsWithValue", ???)
  case None #::xs => ("existsButNull", Nil)
  case Stream.empty => ("notExists", Nil)
}
```

Note that if value exists and is not `NULL` and if **there are more than 1 record of it** then `value` can't be `NULL`. For example, this situation is **NOT** possible

```
1 123 "Value1"
2 123 "Value2"
3 123  NULL    -- NOT possible  
4 123 "Value4"
```

It has to do with pattern matching of `Stream` + `Option` but I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern matching on a stream is probably not a good idea, I'm assuming the number of elements being returned is small enough to fit into memory?  You would only work with a stream if it's likely that the elements won't fit in memory, otherwise it's much easier to convert the stream to a list, and then work with the list:

```
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  SQL("SELECT value from table1 WHERE externalId = 333")
    .map { case Row(value: Option[String]) => value }
    .toList
} match {
  case Nil => ("notExists", Nil)
  case List(None) => ("existsButNull", Nil)
  case xs => ("existsWithValue", xs.flatMap(_.toList))
}
```

Comment: believe you or not, I've solved it the same way. Thanks, Merry Christmas to you too.